# unable to remove google account from lenovo vibe p1 m

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, lenovo

I have added my gmail account in my lenovo vibe p1 option  m mobile phone but I am not getting any option to remove the account from the mobile. I searched in settings->Accounts but no such option is given. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Go to setting > google > tap the account u want to remove > then tap the  recent page button (square shape ) 3 times then  remove option will be shown !

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - Accounts - Google, this should put on a menu with your account at the top and all the sync options under it. Tap the 3-dot overflow menu in the upper right corner and select Remove Account.

Answer (score 0):

to see the REMOVE ACCOUNT option, you need to long press the menu button on the phone. it will do the trick.